# How can I "unsubscribe" from a message thread on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Sometimes, for some private get together or a heated conversation I end up being on the end of a long Facebook message thread with up to 10 Facebook users. And these users, instead of replying to the original sender, reply to all. That is fine with me as long as I can leave the thread.

I do get other important messages in my inbox so I do not want to disable notifications for it. On the other hand it is not so fun to clear 15-20 messages with the same reply

> Sure I can make it. See you there !

Is there a way that I am not seeing to exit the message thread (an "un-tag method") so when someone replies all I do not get it in my inbox ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now [unsubscribe from group Facebook messages](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=187652797949395).  If you've updated to the newest version of messages/email, then you can click on the "Action" menu and unsubscribe from there.  A notice will go out to everyone in that thread letting them know you've unsubscribed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to each group you are a member, at the upper part, click "Edit Settings."

Choose your preference under "notify me when...."

Answer (score 0):

Go to the group you want to leave, scroll down (depending on the device you are using), click where it says INFO, the options will pop up and depending on what you want to do, choose from there.